# Volume Elements Inside The Warp Bubble

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, volume, warp-drives

I'm trying to understand how to calculate proper spacelike volumes of metric tensors that have off-diagonal terms. Right now I'm considering a slower-than-light Alcubierre metric:

$ds^2=(v^2f^2-1)dt^2-2vfdtdx+dx^2$, where I'm making $v=0.5$. Also, I'm considering $t=0$, so $f=\frac{tanh(x+4)-tanh(x-4)}{2tanh(4)}$.

Switching to a new time coordinate $d\tau=dt+\frac{vf}{1-v^2f^2}dx
$ makes the determinant of the 3-metric $\frac{1}{1-v^2f^2}$, which has this graph:

[image]

However I'm not sure about this because I would have expected the volume elements inside the bubble to be smaller than those out, since they are contracted on one side and restored to normal size on the other end. Would this assumption be correct?

Answer (score 2):

Usually inside the bubble $f = 1$ and the space is Minkowskian, so space is completely flat.

Also, perhaps you could be more interested in a coordinate invariant statement such as the expansion $θ = \nabla_{μ} U^{\mu}$ which gives
$$ θ=v \frac{x−x_s}{r} \frac{df(r)}{dr} $$

where $x_s$ is the center of the bubble or position of a ship. That is what is drawn in the original paper.

Comment: But wouldn't it still be different from the minkowskian space outside the bubble, where f is 0? I would assume so because this would make the metric different.

Comment: Also, are you saying that taking the integral of $\theta$ would yield a better answer to the question than a new time coordinate would?

Comment: Regarding the first comment, f=1 is minkowski, you just need a change of coordinates to redefine a new X = x - x_s(t) to see that, and using the fact that v = dx_s/dt.

Comment:  is the expansion (scalar), not a coordinate. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raychaudhuri_equation

Comment: Yes indeed, not a coordinate. I was just thinking that that if $\theta$ is the rate of change of the curvature per coordinate time (although I'm not sure that's what it always is), integrating it could somehow give the curvature at a single moment.

Comment: It is not really the rate of change of the curvature, but the rate of change of the volume of a ball of matter (or light) under the influence of the curvature.

Comment: And it's rate of change wrt the proper time of a comoving observer? If so, would the observer be in the center of the bubble?

Comment: Yes, exactly as you said.

Comment: So then, would the rate of change be measured by $(v^2-c^2)t$ instead of $t$?

Comment: Do I understand correctly that the "York time" and the trace of the expansion tensor are the same?  And if so, how does this equal to the covariant derivative of the eulerian observer's 4-velocity for the warp drive?

Comment: I would suggest to create a new question for it.

Comment: I have taken your suggestion and put it as a separate question. @Rexcirus https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/798061/how-does-the-york-time-measure-the-expansion-of-space-why-is-it-equal-to-the